# PHP Session unsets all sessions

Tags: php, session, session-variables, logout

I'm making an online Doctor Appointment app.

I have two websites:

- A patient website that allows patients to schedule an appointment with doctors at a hospital (Client Side)
- A hospital website that allows doctors to view appointment requests.

Problem is if I logout either of the pages, all of them log out. What's the issue?

Hospital Website Logout Script

```
<?php
    session_start();

    if (isset($_SESSION['hid'])) {
      session_unset();
      header("location: login.php");
    }
?>
```

Client Side Logout Script

```
<?php
    session_start();

    if (isset($_SESSION['id'])) {
        session_unset();
        header("location: login.php");
    }
?>
```

Comment: are both the sites on same host ?

Comment: Well that's weird, I have never tested it before. Perhaps `session_destroy` instead of unset would work?

Comment: they must be somehow sharing the same session data.

Comment: @georoot they both run on localhost but different folders and databases.database is only shared when querying doctor's details to display on the client's website.

Comment: @phiter session_destroy() doesnt solve it.

Comment: @DevDonkey sessionon client side is set using the user's id autogenerated on signup and hospital session is set with hospital id.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add a`session_unset()` before `session_destroy()`

```
if (isset($_SESSION['id'])) {
    session_unset();
    session_destroy();    
    header("location: login.php");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can unset the session by setting the value to `false`. In this way, it will only log out from one website only.

Hospital Website Logout Script

```
<?php
    session_start();

    if (isset($_SESSION['hid'])) {
        $_SESSION['hid'] = 0;
        session_destroy();
        header("location: login.php");
    }
?>
```

Client Side Logout Script

```
<?php
    session_start();

    if (isset($_SESSION['id'])) {
        $_SESSION['id'] = 0;
        session_destroy();
        header("location: login.php");
    }
?>
```